# Relacionar un nombre acorde con su coincidencia en un rango

Tags: python

Estoy intentando dividir mis alumnos acorde con sus nombres mediante python.
Si tiene su letra de la a a la m va al grupo 1 y si está entre la n a la z al grupo 2
Cuando ejecuto el siguiente script obtengo la opción de que siempre está en el grupo 2, cuando su nombre empieza por A

```
variable_num =[]
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('m')+1):
variable_num.append(chr(i))

variable_num=str(variable_num)
nombre_alumno = input('Nombre del alumno:')
nombre_alumno_letra = str(nombre_alumno[0:1])

if nombre_alumno_letra == variable_num:
    nom_alumno = 'Grupo 1'
else:
    nom_alumno = 'Grupo 2''
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Probablemente quieras preguntar `if nombre_alumno_letra in variable_num`

Comment: he quitado la etiqueta [tag:pycharm] pues el IDE no es relevante en estas preguntas. Así, si alguien mira esa etiqueta encontrará preguntas _específicas_ de PyCharm.

Comment: del mismo modo, se recomienda no usar encabezados tipo "Python" pues el lenguaje ya lo indican las etiquetas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La versión simple de tu código:

```
nombre_alumno = input('Nombre del alumno:')
if nombre_alumno[0].lower() in "abcdefghijklm":
    grupo_alumno = 'Grupo 1'
else:
    grupo_alumno = 'Grupo 2'
print(grupo_alumno)
```

Para sacar el primer caracter del nombre, basta con `nombre_alumno[0]`. También tienes que convertirlo a minúsculas para compararlo con las letras del primer grupo: no sabes como lo van a ingresar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en el lenguaje de python y no controlo a este nivel. Funciona genial

Answer (score 0):

Solo para ampliar la respuesta apunto los errores y por qué:

1.

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('m')+1):
    variable_num.append(chr(i))
    
    variable_num=str(variable_num)
```

Esto en sí mismo son dos errores: Primero es innecesario invocar `str()` porque `chr()` ya devuelve un valor de tipo str, y segundo es que `variable_num=str(variable_num)` convierte la variable de tipo lista a una variable de tipo tupla, que provoca un error de tipo `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` en el siguiente ciclo del for porque la variable `variable_num` ya no es una lista sino una tupla de tipo "str" y las tuplas son inmutables, es decir, una vez creadas ya no las puedes modificar ni ampliar (no puede hacer `.append()`).

2.

```
   if nombre_alumno_letra == variable_num:
        nom_alumno = 'Grupo 1'
    else:
        nom_alumno = 'Grupo 2''
```

Usas la variable `nom_alumno` pero no está declarada fuera del bucle ni tampoco la retornas de ninguna forma por lo que en realidad no estás haciendo más que sobre-escribirla una y otra vez con el texto "Grupo 1" y "Grupo 2" (con el detalle de que quizás se te ha escapado una doble comilla al final de 'Grupo 2'') y cuando termina el bucle todas las variables locales dentro del bucle `for` desaparecen y no pueden reclamarse después.

3.

```
nombre_alumno_letra = str(nombre_alumno[0:1])
```

Es innecesario igualmente usar `str()` porque la salida de `input()` ya es de tipo "str"

Hay más apreciaciones pero son sobre todo de concepto e idiomáticas que errores de sintaxis. Espero que esto te ayude, un saludo.